# Remove all of the commas in swagger model documentation

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I want to get rid of the commas in swagger's model documentation.  For example:

[image]

Each property (other than the last one) is described with a comma at the end of the string.  How can I get rid of that?  I tried an OperationFilter but the commas seem to be added later than that (perhaps in the UI?) *(Edit: confirmed, see below.)*

I am using swashbuckle with a C# project, if it matters.

Edit: As requested, a sample of the code.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        // "HumanReadableTypeName" is irrelevant to the question but
        // selects the schema name as namespace + type name
        c.CustomSchemaIds(HumanReadableTypeName);
        c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
        c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlComments);
    });
}

public class ScopeResponseModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Id of the administrative scope.
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the administrative scope.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description of the administrative scope.
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether the administrative scope is built-in.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsBuiltIn { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates the built-in "All" scope.  There will be
    /// exactly one scope with this property set to <c>true</c>.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsAllScope { get; set; }
}
```

I checked the `swagger.json` file and it does not contain the commas that appear in the screenshot.  So they must be coming from the UI code.

How can I disable that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: @HelderSepu code snippet included above; however, I believe I have confirmed that the commas are coming from the SwaggerUI code which I have not customized in any way.

Comment: Im trying to reproduce it... What version of swashbuckle are you using?

Comment: Your model looks OK on the latest version of SwaggerUI: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=ApiEx&defaultModelExpandDepth=2&defaultModelRendering=model#/ApiExplorer/ApiExplorer_Post

Comment: I moved on from SwaggerUI to Redoc and it doesn't have the problem.  However I just checked and @HelderSepulveda is correct, the latest version of SwaggerUI also seems to render differently so doesn't have the problem.